# How to make dynamic plot with dataset of each iteration in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, plot, dynamic

I already have datasets of each iterarion, df1, df2, df3..., (same column numbers, different row numbers), I want to create a dynamic plot to show the progress of my algo, but I do not know how to display df1,df2 in a for loop. Here is my code:

```
cols <- c("1" = "red", "0" = "blue")
saveGIF({
for (i in 1:5){  
a=ggplot(df&i, 
aes(x=x1,  y=x2, colour =type))  +   
geom_point(alpha = 1,shape=21, size =3)+ 
scale_colour_manual(values = cols)+
xlim(-20,10)+ylim(-10,20)
print(a)}
}, interval = .2, movie.name="test.gif")
```

Or if you have suggestions to use other methods to make dynamic plot, please let me know, thanks. 
df1(100*3) is the dataframe after first iteration, df2(85*3) is the dataframe after second iteration, I want to create a animated gif.

```
> head(dataframe2)
        x1       x2 type
1 1.585476 4.792934    1
2 1.645032 5.435548    1
3 1.150726 6.064459    1
4 1.168859 5.889715    1
5 1.830974 5.088805    1
6 1.326834 5.162828    1
```

type is a factor, 0 or 1 , for different colors. thanks.

Comment: (1) By *"dynamic plot"*, do you mean animated gif? (2) I assume your `df&i` is completely speculative, as this in R means *"vectorized logical **AND** between the objects `df` and `i`"*. (3) It would really help to have a reproducible question. This does not need real or even complex data, just something showing progression in a way that is important/relevant to you.

Comment: `df&i` is not valid R syntax to refer to a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tricks to get your code working.

1. If you have data.frames named `df1`, `df2`, etc, put them in a list with `mget/ls`.
2. In the loop, refer to the data.frames indexing the list created in point 1.

Something like the following.

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)

df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+"))

cols <- c("1" = "red", "0" = "blue")
saveGIF({
  for(i in seq_along(df_list)){
    a <- ggplot(df_list[[i]], 
                aes(x = x1,  y = x2, colour = type))  +   
      geom_point(alpha = 1,shape = 21, size = 3)+ 
      scale_colour_manual(values = cols) +
      xlim(-20, 10) + ylim(-10, 20)
    print(a)
  }
}, interval = .2, movie.name="test.gif")
```

[image]

**Test data creation code.**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = -20:10, x2 = sin(-20:10), type = factor(0))
tmp <- lapply(1:4, function(m) {
  data.frame(x1 = df1$x1, x2 = df1$x2*m, type = factor(m %% 2))
})
names(tmp) <- paste0("df", 2:5)
list2env(tmp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!